# Coqをopam経由でインストール

Tags: macos, ocaml

現在mac上でopam install coq を実行していて、errorは吐かれないのですが二時間待ってもmakeが完了していないようです。そこでお聞きしたいのですが通常Coqをinstallするにはどれくらいの時間がかかるのでしょうか？ セットアップが間違っているのかcoqが大きすぎてmakeに時間がかかっているだけなのかはっきりさせたいです。以下実行の様子です。

```
$ opam list
 Packages matching: installed
 Name         Installed        Synopsis
base-bigarray base
base-threads  base
base-unix     base
camlp5        7.06.10-g84ce6cc4 Preprocessor-pretty-printer of OCaml
conf-m4       1                 Virtual package relying on m4
num           1.1               The legacy Num library for arbitrary-precision integer an
ocaml         4.07.1            The OCaml compiler (virtual package)
ocaml-config  1                 OCaml Switch Configuration
ocaml-system  4.07.1            The OCaml compiler (system version, from outside of opam)
ocamlfind     1.8.0             A library manager for OCaml

$ opam install coq
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install coq 8.9.1

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
[coq.8.9.1] found in cache

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>   
Processing  1/2: [coq: make]
```

環境は
OS→ OSX, memory→ 8G

opam、coq、stackoverflow共に初心者です。誤り等ございましたらご指摘いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

単に `opam install coq` しただけではそこまでの時間はかからない印象です。

Mac 環境が手元にないので Ubuntu 環境で `time` コマンドを使って測ってみたところ、10 分程度でした。

```sh
$ time opam install coq
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install coq 8.9.1

<><> Gathering sources ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[coq.8.9.1] found in cache

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
∗ installed coq.8.9.1
Done.

real    3m54.431s
user    10m26.815s
sys 1m53.153s
```

私の環境:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-7500U x 4
- メモリ: 16 GB
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- OPAM 2.0.0 (`opam --version`)
- OCaml 4.07.0 (`opam switch`)